# How to make Bootstrap dropdown menu toggle subitems?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I am developing a website using Bootstrap. I have responsive menu that turns into hamburger on mobile devices. Now, my now already dropdown has dropdown menu items, and when one drops down, it covers the rest of the menu. How could I stop this?

Example:

```
MENU
    item1
        subitem1.1
        subitem1.2
    item2
        subitem2.1
        subitem2.2
    item3
    item4
```

See how it looks like here: http://finestof.me/buona-vista-resort/

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inspecting your dropdowns it looks like you have interfering css on your ".dropdown". Specifically on ".navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu".
It should have:

```css
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
}
```

So you need to remove:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: That's it! This is Bootstrap's css, so I overrode it with !important. Thank you so much!!